# How to Pivot/Stack for multi header column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

```py
np.random.seed(2022)  # added to make the data the same each time
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','A' ,'B','B'], ['min','max','min','max']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4),columns=cols)
df.index.name = 'item'

             A                   B          
           min       max       min       max
item                                        
0     0.009359  0.499058  0.113384  0.049974
1     0.685408  0.486988  0.897657  0.647452
2     0.896963  0.721135  0.831353  0.827568
```

There are two column headers and while working with csv, I get a blank column name for every other column on unmerging.

I want result that looks like this. How can I do it?
I tried to use pivot table but couldn't do it.

[image]

Comment: Post text, not images of text

Comment: `df = df.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index()` is probably better, as it's a completely long form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = (
    df.stack(level=0)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "title"})
    .sort_values(by=["title", "item"])
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   item title       max       min
0     0     A  0.762221  0.737758
2     1     A  0.930523  0.275314
4     2     A  0.746246  0.123621
1     0     B  0.044137  0.264969
3     1     B  0.577637  0.699877
5     2     B  0.601034  0.706978
```

---

Then to CSV:

```
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```